# How can each element of a numpy array be operated upon according to its relative value?

Tags: python, numpy

Let say that we have an array

```
a = np.array([10,30,50, 20, 10, 90, 0, 25])
```

The pseudo code for what I want -

```
if a[x] > 80 then perform funcA on a[x]
if 40 < a[x] <= 80 then perform funcB on a[x]
if a[x] <= 40 then perform funcC on a[x]
```

What is the cleanest way to perform this using numpy functions?

Comment: Can `funcA()` etc. be expressed in terms of NumPy ufuncs?  What do these functions  do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Usually, you try to avoid any Python loops over NumPy arrays -- that's why you use NumPy in the first place.  For the sake of example, I assume that `funcA()` adds 1 to all elements, `funcB()` adds 2 and `funcC()` adds 3 (please elaborate what they really do for a more tailor-made example).  To achieve what you want, you can do this:

```
subset_a = a > 80
subset_b = (40 < a) & (a <= 80)
subset_c = a <= 40
a[subset_a] += 1
a[subset_b] += 2
a[subset_c] += 3
```

This uses [NumPy advanced indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing).  For example `a > 80` evaluates to an array of Boolean values which can be used to select the entries in the array fulfilling the condition.

Comment: Can you really do `a[40 < a <= 80]`?  My version of numpy throws an error when I tried.

Comment: My numpy throws an error on 'and': a = np.array([10,30,50, 20, 10, 90, 0, 25]); subset_b = 40 < a and a <= 80; ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().

Comment: @Spacedman - To do `a[40 < a <=80]` you just need to do `a[(40 < a) & (a <= 80)]`  You have to use `&` and not `and`, and you have to use parenthesis. `40 < a and a <= 80` won't work. `(40 < a) & (a <= 80)` will.

Comment: Thanks to all - with Joe Kington's comment this provides exactly what I need.

Comment: Thanks for the comments -- fixed the answer again.

Comment: One more thing I just learned (for readability) subset_b = numpy.logical_and(a > 40, a <= 80).  Fewer parenthesis to forget.

Answer (score 8):

Look at numpy.piecewise. I think you want:

```
np.piecewise( a, [a > 80, (40 < a) & (a <= 80), a <= 40], [funcA, funcB, funcC] )
```

Comment: This also copies everything twice, but I like it anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I like this:

```
b = np.empty(a.shape)
b[a < 40] = funcA(a[a < 40])
b[(a > 40) & (a <= 80)] = funcB(a[(a > 40) & (a <= 80)])
b[a > 80] = funcC(a[a > 80])
```

This avoids weird behavior when `funcA` sets an element of `a` that had been 39 to 41, for instance, thus bringing it into the range for `funcB`.

Comment: I avoided to do this because it creates copies, performs the actions on the copied data and copies again to store the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you need more complex functions you can use

```
      newfunc=numpy.vectorize(lambda x: func(x))
      result=newfunc(yourArray)
```

where func(x) is your function.